# Mouse hover - libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, onclicklistener

Is there any listener in libgdx that would allow me to detect just mouse hover not pressed just hover. In the button class of scene 2D you have 2 methods isOver and isPressed but they do the same thing ... Anyone else having this problem? Is there another way to detect mouse hover over actor?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's the [`ClickListener`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/utils/ClickListener.html) which can be attached to an `Actor` and it offers events like the following ones:

```
public void enter(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor fromActor)
public void exit(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor toActor)
```

The `enter` event basiscally means that the mouse started hovering over the actor, `exit` means it "left" the area of the actor. It also has a `clicked` event which you can use to execute some action in the end.

Comment: Do you have to add the function separately like make a new click listener for each one and add it to the actor or you can make one with all of them and add to the actor. Anyway i did both and the enter and exit don't seem to work...

Comment: You make your own `HoverListener extends ClickListener` and override the both methods. Then do `actor.addListener(new HoverListener())`.

Comment: For me it worked this way. Don't forget the `stage.act()` in your render method.

Comment: Ok now i got it. I forgot the stage.act(). I made my own class and i have overrided the methods and it didn't work because the stage.act() was missing. Thanks for the info.

Comment: After some more coding i am experiencing another problem. When i click the button without moving the mouse the exit method is activated. I don't know why this is happening...

Comment: if the click releases the mouse output, it can validate if the "pointer" equals -1