# How to make buttons play sound in Libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx

How can I make a TextButton play a sound when the mouse hovers over it? Something like:

```
TextButton play = new TextButton("Play", textButtonStyle);
play.addListener(new ButtonHoverListener() {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: See this question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23174722/mouse-hover-libgdx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23174722/mouse-hover-libgdx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
play.addListener(new InputListener(){

        boolean playing = false;

        @Override
        public void enter(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor fromActor) {
            super.enter(event, x, y, pointer, fromActor);
            if (!playing) {
                Sound sound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("data/mysound.mp3"));
                sound.play(1F);
                playing = true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void exit(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor toActor) {
            super.exit(event, x, y, pointer, toActor);
            playing = false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ohhhh thanks. I actually read the link Alexander Mironov posted and ClickListener has those methods as well.

Comment: InputListener is more generic than ClickListener