# Libgdx How would I go about checking if a mouse is hovering over a TextField?

Tags: java, events, libgdx

Using Libgdx, I'm attempting to find a way to check if the mouse is hovering over a given TextField object.

Buttons in libgdx give the ability to check if the mouse is hovering over it with the #isOver() method. Unfortunately, TextFields do not have this.

You can, however, add a new inputListener where it can invoke events if the TextField if the mouse is hovering, etc. but doesn't allow checking if it is being hovered over.

How would I go about implementing an #isOver() method for TextFields? Thank you.

Comment: see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23174722/mouse-hover-libgdx

Answer (score 3):

You can use [hit()](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html#hit-float-float-boolean-) method from the *Actor* class to check if mouse is in *TextField* (that extending *Actor*) bounds.

To get mouse position you should use [getX()](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.html#getX--) and [getY()](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.html#getX--) methods from *Gdx.input* and then translate them to the *TextField*'s stage's coordinates by using [screenToStageCoordinates()](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Stage.html#screenToStageCoordinates-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2-):

```
TextField textField;

...

//in render() method
Vector2 mouseScreenPosition = new Vector2(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY());
Vector2 mouseLocalPosition = textField.screenToLocalCoordinates(mouseScreenPosition);

if(textField.hit(mouseLocalPosition.x, mouseLocalPosition.y, false) != null) {
    //the mouse is over the TextField
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however, when I invoke getStage, it returns null every single time. I don't know why it would?

Comment: You probably did not add the textField to Stage I guess (by calling `stage.addActor`)

Comment: The issue with the stage seems to be resolved, however, the intended purpose doesn't seem to work. It always returns false when I check if the textField is hitting the mouseStagePosition.

Comment: check out my edit - seems that you should call `hit()` on stage not the actor