# How to display a text while hovering on image or texture in libgdx?

Tags: libgdx

I am trying to implement a map of the universe. When mouse on a  pic of the planet simply hovering on the picture, I want to see some information. How to handle this in libgdx?
In the following example, I am trying to give mouseClick sound while hovering, still does not work.

```
   ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton(drawable);
    imageButton.setSize(100,100);
    imageButton.setPosition(100,100);
    imageButton.addListener(new FocusListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean handle(Event event) {
            mouseClick.play();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Here how my override methods @enter and @exit looks`, I created HoverListener and override both methods.

```
@Override
public void enter(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor fromActor) {
    super.enter(event, x, y, pointer, fromActor);
    fromActor.setName("Hello");

}

@Override
public void exit(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor toActor) {
    super.exit(event, x, y, pointer, toActor);

    toActor.setName("Bye");

}
```

Then    `btn_station.addListener(new HoverListener());`
Still no interaction :/

Comment: You need a handler that responds to `enter` and `exit`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23174722/mouse-hover-libgdx

Comment: LibGDX has a Tooltip class. It's a bit odd. A Tooltip is both an Actor itself and an InputListener. So you add it as a listener to the Actor you want to attach it to, and it gets temporarily added to the Stage automatically when the cursor hovers over the Actor its attached to. You can customize TooltipBehavior using the TooltipManager singleton.

Comment: This answer did help me either @EntangledLoops

Comment: @full_steak_developer Did you add your object to the `Stage`? Is your stage set as the input handler? Sharing more code will help. Also, `setName()` isn't going to change anything visible. Why not try changing the object's color or position?

Comment: @EntangledLoops you're right position has been changed. I had to add `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);`

Comment: @full_steak_developer Great, added as an answer below for posterity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following:

- You stage is the input processor: `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage)`
- Your `Actor` is on the stage: `stage.addActor(actor)`
- The size of your actor is set: `actor.setSize(100f, 100f)`
- You handle input events correctly (implement and override relevant interfaces)

As per your response to my comments, it sounds like in this case you did not set the stage as the input processor.